# Arrays with inconsistent numbers

Tags: machine-learning, python-3.6, linear-regression

This is just a code sample on a tutorial that I was copying and I'm constantly having this error. Can someone give me an explicit and detailed solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



from sklearn import datasets,linear_model


house_price=[245, 312, 279, 308, 199, 405, 324, 319, 255]
size= [1400, 1600, 1700, 1875, 1100, 1550, 2350, 2450, 1425, 1700]

size2 = np.array(size).reshape((-1,1))
print(size2)



regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(size2, house_price)
print("coefficient: \n" ,regr.coef_)
print("intercept: \n", regr.intercept_)


def graph(formula, x_range):
    x = np.array(x_range)
    y = eval(formula)
    plt.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of house prices does not match the number of sizes (elements in array). They need to match. Otherwise, add a `np.nan` (or some imputed value like the median) where a value is missing. E.g.:

```
house_price=[245, 312, 279, 308, 199, 405, 324, 319, 255, np.nan]
size= [1400, 1600, 1700, 1875, 1100, 1550, 2350, 2450, 1425, 1700]
```